# vector from sql statements in DolphinDB database

Tags: dolphindb

How to generate a vector from a SELECT statement in DolphinDB database? Looks like a SELECT statement always generates a table, even if only one column is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use exec instead of select. See the example below.

```
t = table(1 2 1 2 3 as id, 1..5 as value)
exec distinct(id) as id from t order by id
```